# It is possible edit simple slack message after it is sent?

Tags: postman, slack-api

I have url of type https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX to which i send data (using postman for testing) like this:

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "block_id": "section_id_123",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "hello world"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to edit this "hello world" text, after the message is sent, via same url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you are using to post the message is **'Incoming Webhook'**

Incoming webhooks are one-way messaging and **does not allow edit or deletes.**

 https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#posting_with_webhooks